# autocomplete with dynamically generated fields

Tags: jquery, dynamic, input, autocomplete

I have a jQuery autocomplete working perfectly for a statically named text box.

My problem is that my text box is being generated by a jquery script that created the name with an incremental number afterwards. As such each input box that I need to have autocomplete functionality is different.

How can I edit my autocomplete script to work for any input box with a specific name?

I am using codeigniter and jquery 1.7.

My view is:

```
<table class="authors-list">
  <tr><td></td><td>Product</td><td>Qty</td><td>Price/Cube</td><td>Discount</td><td>treated</td></tr>
  <tr>
   <td><a class="deleteRow"> <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/assets/images/no.jpg" /></a></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="product" name="product" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="pricepercube" name="pricepercube" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="discount" name="discount" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="treated" name="treated" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

// script to generate additional rows. input name is appended with counter value

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1;
jQuery("table.authors-list").on('change','input[name^="qty"]',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr>'+
      ' <td><a class="deleteRow"> <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/assets/images/no.jpg" /></a></td>' +
      ' <td><input type="text" id="product_' +  counter + '" name="product_' +  counter + '" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" /></td>' +
      ' <td><input type="text" id="qty_' + counter + '" name="qty_' + counter + '" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" /></td>'+
      ' <td><input type="text" id="pricepercube_' + counter + '" name="pricepercube_' + counter + '" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" /></td>'+
      ' <td><input type="text" id="discount_' + counter + '" name="discount_' + counter + '" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" /></td>'+
      ' <td><input type="text" id="treated_   ' + counter + '" name="treated_   ' + counter + '" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" /></td>'+
      ' </tr>');
    jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
});

jQuery("table.authors-list").on('click','.deleteRow',function(event){
 if ($(this).parents('table').find('tr').length >  2) { 
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 }else{
  alert ('Form must have at least one row')
 }

});
</script>
```

//script for autocomplete. currently works on the statically created input `product`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $("#product").autocomplete({
          source: "get_sku_codes",
          messages: {
          noResults: '',
          results: function() {}
      }       

        });
      });
</script>
```

How can I modify my autocomplete field to reference the correct input field - the input field has the correct name?

Can I do something like: `'input[name^="qty"]'` or is it better to use `$this`?

As mentioned it is working for the static field `product` but I need it to work with the dynamically created fields, which will be: `product_1`, `product_2`, `product_3` etc... keeping in mind that I am not sure how many rows the user will add.

**UPDATE as per Beardfist**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1;
jQuery("table.authors-list").on('change','input[name^="qty"]',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr>'+
      ' <td><a class="deleteRow"> <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/assets/images/no.jpg" /></a></td>' +
      ' <td><input type="text" id="product_' +  counter + '" name="product_' +  counter + '" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" /></td>' +
      ' <td><input type="text" id="qty_' + counter + '" name="qty_' + counter + '" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" /></td>'+
      ' <td><input type="text" id="pricepercube_' + counter + '" name="pricepercube_' + counter + '" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" /></td>'+
      ' <td><input type="text" id="discount_' + counter + '" name="discount_' + counter + '" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" /></td>'+
      ' <td><input type="text" id="treated_   ' + counter + '" name="treated_   ' + counter + '" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" /></td>'+
      ' </tr>');
    jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);

        $("#product_"+counter).autocomplete({ 
          source: "get_sku_codes",
          messages: {
          noResults: '',
          results: function() {}
      }       

        });

});

jQuery("table.authors-list").on('click','.deleteRow',function(event){
 if ($(this).parents('table').find('tr').length >  2) {  //get number of rows(TR's) in table 
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 }else{
  alert ('Form must have at least one row') // alert if only one row left in table
 }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Looking through the docs, there doesn't seem to be a way to delegate the attachment of the `autocomplete` like you would an event. I think your best bet would be to attach it at the time of the element creation. That way you know it exists at the time and you should have the id available to you as you used it to create the element.

Comment: Thanks BeardFist, any advice on how to do this? would I do this in variable newrow `jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);`? is this the right idea or am I way off the mark? keep in mind that the autocomplete source for the lookup is referencing a model from my view (Codeigniter). Thanks again for your time and input.

Comment: You could try adding `$("#product_"+counter).autocomplete({...` right after the `.append()`

Comment: Hi @Beardfist, sorry for my late reply. I have updated the question with my updated code. This is not triggering correctly as I see no XHR requests n developer tools. so my syntax not working. any help appreciated. cheers,

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need counters in this case. You should use a Class (.) instead of an ID (#) for your autocomplete.

Like this: 
$(".product").autocomplete({  ...

Then as you are adding new rows dynamically with .append() you need to put that autocomplete right after appending the row (not before) so it is available with your new DOM everytime you add a new row.